# A recursive solution to symmetirc tree

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, tree

I tried to solve a  symmetric tree problem

> Given a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (ie, symmetric around its center).
>
> For example, this binary tree `[1,2,2,3,4,4,3]` is symmetric:
>
> ```
>     1
>    / \
>   2   2
>  / \ / \
> 3  4 4  3
> ```
>
> But the following `[1,2,2,null,3,null,3]` is not:
>
> ```
>     1
>    / \
>   2   2
>    \   \
>    3    3
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>   Bonus points if you could solve it both recursively and iteratively.

My solution with recursion

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def isSymmetric(self, root):
        if not root: return True #None is symmetic 
        return self.isMirror(root.left, root.right)


    def isMirror(self, l, r):
        if not l and not r: return True #base case 1
        if not l or not r: return False #base case 2
        if l.val != r.val: return False #base case 3
        #recur case 
        left = self.isMirror(l.left, r.right)
        right = self.isMirror(l.right, r.left)
        return left and right
```

I assumed it as a decent solution to this problem but get a low score

> Runtime: 32 ms, faster than 24.42% of Python online submissions for Symmetric Tree.
>   Memory Usage: 12.2 MB, less than 5.08% of Python online submissions for Symmetric Tree.

How could improve the my solution?

Comment: You present input data both as a list and as a tree. Which one is the actual input form? If it is a list of integers, possibly you could do a recursive analysis just on that list and save the time needed for constructing a tree of linked `TreeNode` objects?

Comment: You 'accepted' my answer, which should confirm my modification is correct and resolves your problem. If so, do you mind to share the scores your modified algorithm achieves?

Comment: Where are you submitting these answers to get rankings like this?

Comment: @Shawson Possibly it's [Geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/symmetric-tree-tree-which-is-mirror-image-of-itself/)? Or may be the [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the most obvious part is here

```
    left = self.isMirror(l.left, r.right)
    right = self.isMirror(l.right, r.left)
    return left and right
```

there's no need to perform the second test if the first one returns `False`:

```
    if not self.isMirror(l.left, r.right): return False
    if not self.isMirror(l.right, r.left): return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Appart from the optimization provided by [@CiaPan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/216642/84718), you could try using an inner function to reduce the need for attributes lookups and accelerate symbols resolution speed:

```
class Solution(object):
    def isSymmetric(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return True

        def isMirror(left, right):
            if left is None and right is None:
                return True
            elif left is None or right is None:
                return False
            elif left.val != right.val:
                return False
            else:
                return isMirror(left.left, right.right) and isMirror(left.right, right.left)

        return isMirror(root.left, root.right)
```

Alternatively, you could try the iterative approach which is usually implemented using a `deque` to perform a breadth first search:

```
from collections import deque


class Solution(object):
    def isSymmetric(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return True

        rights = deque([root.right])
        lefts = deque([root.left])
        while lefts:
            left = lefts.popleft()
            right = right.popleft()
            if left is None and right is None:
                pass
            elif left is None or right is None:
                return False
            elif left.val != right.val:
                return False
            else:
                lefts.append(left.left)
                lefts.append(left.right)
                rights.append(right.right)
                rights.append(right.left)

        return True
```

Comment: As it often happens, optimization needs to fit the actual data characteristics. With BSF one should remember that a full binary tree has \$ 2^d \$ items at the level of depth \$d\$ , so the queue can grow much faster (and larger) than a stack. On the other hand with DSF a stack can grow huge if the tree is degenerated to a list.